# interfaces as parameters of a function

Tags: c#, interface

I have an issue, hope someone can help me a bit. I have the following interface :

```
public interface ITaskService
{
    ITaskBase GetTask(IRequestBase request);
}
```

i want to implement the method something like this :

```
public ITaskBase GetTask(Request request) 
{

}
```

Where the request is a model that looks like this :

```
public class Request:IRequestBase
{
    public DateTime CheckIn { get; set; }

    public DateTime CheckOut { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting a compilation error that says the class does not implement the interface `ITaskService` , but I don't get it why the request parameter is inherited from the `IRequestBase` interface

Comment: That's not enough the signature has to be identical.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make `ITaskService` generic.

```
public interface ITaskService<T> where T : IRequestBase
{
    ITaskBase GetTask(T request);
}
```